# Writing Data Point Name Just Above the Data Point in Python Plotly

Tags: python, graph, plotly

I have a dataset and I plotted using plotly python

[image]

The name of the models is shown as a legend on the right side which makes it a little difficult to interpret. Is there any way to write the model name just above the color circle represent on the graph similar to what shown below? Something similar in mathplotlib will also help me.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You  need to add labels in you scatter statement.

```
import plotly.express as px
#df data
fig = px.scatter(df, x="latency", y="AP", text="type", size_max=60)
fig.update_traces(textposition='top center')
```